# Java uso de if y else con string

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en esto, deseo saber como hacer que cuadren los caracteres que el tipo de cargo al que es sea igual a la letra

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Pedro
 */
public class Sueldo_de_un_trabajor {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int horas_semanales;
       float total;
       
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Cantidad de Horas trabajadas: ");
        horas_semanales = teclado. nextInt();
         
        System.out.print("grupo de Clase del Tarabajador\n"
        +"Grupo A\n"
        +"Gurpo B\n"
        +"Grupo C\n"
        +"Grupo D\n :");
       String cargos = teclado.nextLine();
        
       if (cargos.equals(A))
       {
           
       }
           
       }
}
```

Comment: ¿No debería de ser: un cargo pertence a un grupo y a un grupo pertenecen varios cargos?

Answer (score 0):

Si es un string tienes que usar para comparar en un if el equal, voy a meterte el equalsIgnoreCase porque con este metodo compara si son mayúsculas y minúsculas es decir da igual si pones A o a.

Luego usando un else if que quiere decir si la primera condicion no se cumple va pasando a los else if linea a linea

Y por ultimo un else normal donde sacamos por pantalla error el cargo no coincide con ninguno

```
 if (cargos.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
        System.out.println("Pasamos por el grupo A");
    }else if (cargos.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
        System.out.println("pasamos por el grupo B");
    }else if (cargos.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
        System.out.println("Pasamos por el grupo C");
    }else if (cargos.equalsIgnoreCase("d")) {
        System.out.println("Pasamos por el grupo D");
    }else {
        System.out.println("Error el cargo no coincide con ninguno "+cargos);
    }
```